# Store specific keys and values into an array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a `JSON` data consists of many keys and values and I'm trying to extract some and not all keys and values. Here's my `JSON` data:

```js
    "projectID": 1,
    "projectName": "XXX",
    "price": 0.2,
    "regStart":{
        "$date": "2021-12-15T16:00:00.00Z"
    },
    "regEnd":{
        "$date": "2021-12-18T16:00:00.00Z"
    },
    "saleStart":{
        "$date": "2021-12-20T20:00:00.00Z"
    },
    "saleEnd":{
        "$date": "2021-12-15T20:00:00.00Z"
    },
    "totalRaise": 200000,
    "totalSale": 50000,
    "projectStatus": "Ongoing",
```

Now I only wanna store **projectID, projectName and price**. How do I do that? I've written some but not sure how to iterate this data and store into my empty object.

```js
    let result = []
    for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      let tempRes = {}
      // ...no idea how to do it
      result.push(tempRes);
    }
```

Comment: Is that data only one of your object (i.e. it's inside an array)? Because it doesn't really make sense what you are trying to do with the loop if there is only 1 object and only 3 properties that you want.

Comment: is the JSON data is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = {"projectID": 1,
    "projectName": "XXX",
    "price": 0.2,
    "regStart":{
        "$date": "2021-12-15T16:00:00.00Z"
    },
    "regEnd":{
        "$date": "2021-12-18T16:00:00.00Z"
    },
    "saleStart":{
        "$date": "2021-12-20T20:00:00.00Z"
    },
    "saleEnd":{
        "$date": "2021-12-15T20:00:00.00Z"
    },
    "totalRaise": 200000,
    "totalSale": 50000,
    "projectStatus": "Ongoing"}

const result = {};


    Object.keys(arr).forEach(key=>{
            if(['projectID','projectName','price'].includes(key)) {   // you can modify this as per your requirement
            result[key] = arr[key];
    }

});


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Maybe `['projectID', 'projectName', 'price'].includes(key)` is better?

Comment: Yes, true. It can be optimized further. it's done. Updated the answer.

Comment: What about in line: `const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr).filter(([key]) => ['projectID','projectName','price'].includes(key)));`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the property using dot notation. Here's an example:

```js
var data = {
  "projectID": 1,
  "projectName": "XXX",
  "price": 0.2,
  "regStart": {
    "$date": "2021-12-15T16:00:00.00Z"
  },
  "regEnd": {
    "$date": "2021-12-18T16:00:00.00Z"
  },
  "saleStart": {
    "$date": "2021-12-20T20:00:00.00Z"
  },
  "saleEnd": {
    "$date": "2021-12-15T20:00:00.00Z"
  },
  "totalRaise": 200000,
  "totalSale": 50000,
  "projectStatus": "Ongoing"
}

var resultObj = {projectID: data.projectID, projectName: data.projectName, price: data.price}

console.log(resultObj)
```

Comment: How do I store these into the `object` I initialized which is `tempRes`? Also, I wanna store the key and value into the `object`

Comment: @Leo You do `tempRes.projectID = data.projectID`, `tempRes. projectName = data. projectName` etc.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Same as @HaoWu's comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is a util function I wrote a while back.

```js
const removeKeys = (obj, keys, associate = true) => {
  const _obj = associate ? obj : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(_obj, key)) {
      delete _obj[key]
    }
  })

  return _obj
}
```

Usage for your case:

```
const payload = removeKeys(data, ['regStart', 'regEnd', 'saleStart', 'saleEnd', 'totalRaise', 'totalSale', 'projectStatus'], false)
```

Here it is in action: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dq97x8b/)